inequality without using study of function
I need to prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ : $$\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \leq \frac{1}{4}$$ by means of inequalities only, without considering $f(x) = \frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$.
I am trying to show that  the difference $$\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2} - \frac{1}{4}$$ is negative so I found that we need to prove that $$-x^4+4x^3-10x^2+4x-1 \leq 0$$ without any results.
Do you have an idea to prove that?

You are almost done. Just write the inequality you have to show the other way around
$$x^4-4x^3+10x^2-4x+1\ge 0$$ Now note that \begin{align*}x^4-4x^3+10x^2-4x+1&=(x^4-4x^3+6x^2-4x+1)+4x^2\\&=(x-1)^4+(2x)^2\\&\ge 0\end{align*}

Edit : J.W.Tanner's result can also be found out in a similar manner.
We want $$\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \leq \frac{1}{8}$$
This is equivalent to showing (this can be found by cross multiplying, expanding and bringing everything to one side similar to the original problem) $$x^4-8x^3+18x^2+8x+1\ge 0$$
Well, we simply note that \begin{align*}x^4-8x^3+18x^2+8x+1&=(x^4-4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)-(4x^3-12x^2+4x)\\&=(x-1)^4-4x(x^2-3x+1)\\&=(x-1)^4-4x\left[(x-1)^2-x\right]\\&=(x-1)^4-4x(x-1)^2+4x^2\\&=\left[(x-1)^2-2x\right]^2\\&\ge 0\end{align*}
In fact, this is the best we can do. For $x=2\pm\sqrt3$, we have the values $$(1-x)^2=4\pm2\sqrt3=2x$$ $$(1+x^2)=4(2\pm \sqrt3)=4x$$ Plugging everything in, we get $$\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{x\cdot 2x}{(4x)^2}=\frac{2x^2}{16x^2}=\frac18$$ and thus the upper bound is attained, making it the maximum.

thanks a lot, its correct

@FouadEl If you think this answer helps, do kindly accept it.

I don't know what to do to accept it ??

@FouadEl You should see a green checkmark beside the answer. Just select that.

thanks a lot for your help and indication.

@FouadEl No worries!

In fact $(x-1)^4+(2x)^2\gt 0$ strictly, because if $x-1=0$ then $2x\ne0$, and vice versa

Actually we can prove the stronger statement that
$\dfrac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \leq \dfrac{1}{8}.$
First, note that, for $x\lt0$,  $\dfrac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \leq 0\lt\dfrac{1}{8},$ since squares are non-negative.
It remains to consider $x\ge0$.  In that case, we can apply the  AM-GM inequality $\dfrac{a+b}2\ge\sqrt{ab}$
with $a=2x$ and $b=(1-x)^2$, so $a+b=1+x^2$ and $\dfrac{1+x^2}2\ge\sqrt{2x(1-x)^2}.$
Squaring both sides yields $\dfrac{(1+x^2)^2}4\ge2x(1-x)^2$, from which it follows that $\dfrac{x(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\le\dfrac18$.

WLOG $x=\tan y$
So, we have $$f(y)=\tan y\cos^2y(\cos y-\sin y)^2$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin2y(1-\sin2y)}2$$
$$=\dfrac{1-(1-2\sin2y)^2}8$$
Now $1-2\le1-2\sin2y\le1+2$
$\implies0\ge-(1-2\sin2y)^2\ge-9$
So, $f(y)$ attains the maximum value$(=?)$ if $2\sin2y=1$
Notice that $f(y)$ also has a finite minimum value$(=?)$ as well
